# Dynamic sql to count rows in a table gives unexpected result

Tags: sql-server

I get returned NULL when I execute this piece of code. Can you help me understand what is wrong with it? It's basically used to count rows in a table using a dynamic sql statement. Many thanks in advance.

```
DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(4000),
@code    nvarchar(40),
@count    int,
@params nvarchar(4000)

SELECT @sql =  N' SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM   [Table1] WHERE [Column1]='''+quotename(@code)
   SELECT @params = N'@code nvarchar(40), ' +
                    N'@cnt      int      OUTPUT'
   EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, 'AD', @cnt = @count OUTPUT

SELECT @count as x
select @sql as y
```

Let me know please if you need additional details. Appreciate the pointers/help on this. PS. I have tested this manually and the count is more than 1.

Comment: and also give it a value

Comment: you didn't give @ code a value so your @ sql return null. You can either provide a value for it, or wrap quotename(@code) in isnull: isnull(quotename(@ code), 'default_value') + ''''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good practise to pass arguments (`@code`) as params to `sp_executesql`:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (Column1 NVARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO #Table1(Column1) VALUES ('AD'), ('AD');

DECLARE @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @code    NVARCHAR(40),
        @count   INT,
        @params  NVARCHAR(4000);

SELECT @sql =  N'SELECT @cnt = COUNT(*) 
                 FROM #Table1 
                 WHERE [Column1]= @code;'
      ,@params = N'@code NVARCHAR(40), 
                   @cnt  INT OUTPUT';

EXEC [dbo].[sp_executesql] 
       @sql
      ,@params 
      ,@code = 'AD'
      ,@cnt = @count OUTPUT;

SELECT @count AS x;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379168)**</kbd>